# Understand EQU and >> operators on them in RISC-V assembly, with LUI and ADDI

Tags: assembly, riscv, immediate-operand

my prof posted this as one of the answers to a homework problem. Can anyone break this down for me? I don't understand what he is doing with CON1 - CON4 and what the >> and 0x0FFF mean.

```
CON1:   EQU 6000
CON2:   EQU 6245
CON3:   EQU 10000
CON4:   EQU 10245
A:  DM 4                         ; DM is Define Memory

    addi    t1,  x0, A           ; t1 = &A

    lui t0,  (CON1>>12) + ((CON1 & 0x0800)>>11)
    addi    t0,  t0, CON1&0xFFF
    sd  t0,  0(t1)            // Cut and paste from last question of Quiz1
                                      // Blank line between groups of statements
    lui t0,  (CON2>>12) + ((CON2 & 0x0800)>>11)
    addi    t0,  t0, CON2&0xFFF
    sd  t0,  8(t1)

    lui t0,  (CON3>>12) + ((CON3 & 0x0800)>>11)
    addi    t0,  t0, CON3&0xFFF
    sd  t0,  16(t1)

    lui t0,  (CON4>>12) + ((CON4 & 0x0800)>>11)
    addi    t0,  t0, CON4&0xFFF
    sd  t0,  24(t1)
                                      // We need this to avoid the NO INSTRUCTION error
    ebreak x0, x0, 0              ; Suspend program.
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you. We are using RISC-V

Comment: `>>` is right shift. Your prof is splitting the CON addresses into two parts (low 12 bits, top 24 bits) because the `lui` and the `addi` have limited range. Normally this is handled by the assembler automatically.

Comment: @Jester So where does the >>11 play in?

Comment: That is because the `addi` sign extends the immediate so if bit `0x800` is set the value will be interpreted as negative. Adding the bit will compensate for that.

Comment: @Jester Okay, I see. Thanks

Comment: I'm curious, what kind of RISC-V assembler is this?

Comment: @maxschlepzig RVS

Comment: @DanielIlie, do you have a link? I can't find it with google.

Comment: @maxschlepzig Should be somewhere on this page, don't remember where I downloaded it from it was over a year ago. https://riscv.org/download/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the RISC-V base instruction set, each instruction is encoded in 32 bits. That means the space for immediate operands is limited to a few bits. Thus, to get a larger constant into a register (which is with RV32G/RV64G also 32 or 64 bit wide) you need to split it and move the parts with multiple instructions, i.e. 2 with RV32G and up to 8 with RV64G.

With 32 bit RISC-V (RV32G), larger constants can be loaded with the *load upper immediate* (`lui`) and *add immediate* (`addi`) instruction. The immediate operand of `lui` is 20 bit wide while `addi` allows for an immediate operand of 12 bit. Thus, they are sufficient to load constants that use up to 32 bits.

`lui` sign-extends its immediate operand and left-shifts it by 12 bits and loads the result into the destination register. Hence its name. `addi` also sign-extends its immediate operand before adding it.

Thus, with RV32G, to load a larger constant with `lui` followed by `addi` one has to take the upper 20 bits, logical-right-shift them by 12 bits such that the 12 bit left-shift by `lui` is cancelled out. Followed by the masking of the lower 12 bits to get the operand for `addi`.

This is sufficient if `addi` doesn't sign-extends its immediate operand. If it does because the highest bit is set to 1 we have to increase the `lui` operand such that the superfluous sign bits are zeroed-out again in the addition.

Say we denote the high part of our constant `x` with `h`, the low part with `l`, since RISC-V implements two's complement and arithmetic wraps on register overflow, we can use modular arithmetic to see that:

```
     h + l = x                             # taking register widths into account:
 => (h + l) % 2**32  = x % 2**32           # in case l is sign extended:
 => (h + l + e + c) % 2**32  = x % 2**32   # replace e with the additional sign bits:
<=> (h + l + 4294963200 + c) % 2**32  = x % 2**32     # eliminate c:
<=> (h + l + 4294963200 + 4096) % 2**32  = x % 2**32
<=> (h + l) % 2**32  + (4294963200 + 4096) % 2**32  = x % 2**32
<=> (h + l) % 2**32  + 0  = x % 2**32
```

Thus, we have to add 1 to the `lui` immediate operand (which equals 4096 after being left-shifted by 12 bits) if and only if the immediate operand of `addi` is sign-extended.

In your assembly example, the `>>` denotes a right-shift, `<<` a left-shift and `&` logical-and. They are used to implement the described splitting and arithmetic, e.g. in

```
 lui t0,  (CON1>>12) + ((CON1 & 0x0800)>>11)
 addi    t0,  t0, CON1&0xFFF
```

where `CON1 & 0x0800` masks the 12 bit, i.e. the sign bit of the `addi` immediate operand. If it is set then `((CON1 & 0x0800)>>11)` evaluates to 1 and thus cancels out the superfluous sign bits added by the following `addi` instruction. `CON1&0xFFF` masks the lowest 12 bits.

In standard RISC-V assembly all this tedious bit managing can be avoided by just using the *load immediate* (`li`) pseudo-instruction, e.g.:

```
li     t1, 6245
```

Which the assembler automatically translates into the optimal instruction sequence (check e.g. with objdump):

```
lui    t1, 0x2
addi   t1, t1,-1947
```

Alternatively, with the GNU as assembler there are also directives for splitting the operand into the upper and lower part:

```
lui    a1, %hi(6245)
addi   a1, a1, %lo(6245)
```

Which arguably is also more readable than the clutter in your snippet.

This also works with symbols in GNU as, e.g.:

```
.set CON2, 6245

li    a1, 6245

lui   a2, %hi(CON2)
addi  a2, a2, %lo(CON2)

li    a3, CON2

# => a1 == a2 == a3
```

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it.